# Are there any failure-proof instruments on commercial airliners?

Tags: avionics, failures

Let's assume worst case scenario - nighttime over the ocean, complete vacuum failure, perhaps complete electrical failure (in a "fly-by-pulley" plane perhaps), or at least avionics failure.
Is there any instrument on board capable of providing, at very least, horizontal situation indication, so the plane can safely get to a lit area for visual navigation?
Even in my car, I have a 25 cent toy spherical compass in water, that, at very least, can give me such information.  Even a handheld phone has good enough gravity sensors for this. for Is there anything available on the flight deck like this?

Comment: What is a "horizontal situation indication"? You mean if the aircraft is flying level or not? Then no, a wet compass or phone cannot do that in an airplane. There is no "failure proof" instrument, that is why most commercial aircraft have multiple instruments that do the same thing using different methods.

Comment: @RonBeyer a wet compass no, but airliners are equipped with one "old fashioned" version of each instrument, including the artificial horizon.

Comment: @Federico I don't believe that is accurate, if you mean vacuum gyro driven by "old fashioned". For example, see the [A380 cockpit](http://imgproc.airliners.net/photos/airliners/0/9/7/0957790.jpg?v=v40). Notice an artificial horizon on the left is an LCD screen, no "old fashioned" instruments...

Comment: As well, an old-fashioned HSI would fail with vacuum failure, no?

Comment: @RonBeyer, yes, some sort of HSI.   Why couldn't a phone or wet compass do it?

Comment: @aAaaaAaa Because when you bank, you can turn at 1G which means that the "gravity" vector banks with the aircraft. Phones don't sense "gravity", they sense a force vector. Compasses lead/lag turns and have the same "gravity" issues phones have, they don't point down, they align themselves with the force vector pulling them down, which changes in a turn.

Comment: @RonBeyer I was more familiar with the older 320, I admit https://airandspace.si.edu/webimages/highres/WEB10778-2007h.jpg

Comment: Phone or wet compass won't give you anything but a combination of 'down' and whatever acceleration the aircraft is providing. Assuming that true 'down' is what's pulling you into your seat is a deadly mistake (see [Graveyard Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graveyard_spiral)).

Comment: @RonBeyer couldn't a GPS device calculate groundspeed and altitude, and infer from that, at very least, rate of descent or ascent? Not quite horizontal situation, but if it shows 50knots and descending, pilots could probably infer they are in a descending flat stall....

Comment: So which is easier, to make something never fail or to make two thing that never fail at the same time?

Comment: *"couldn't a GPS device calculate groundspeed and altitude ... if it shows 50knots and descending, pilots could probably infer they are in a descending flat stall"* Except when they're not. Stalling is about airspeed and angle of attack, not ground speed. In extreme situations, it's even possible to fly a ground track that moves you *backwards*, especially in a small plane, and be nowhere near a stall of any kind. Just watch out when the wind shifts... And if you have complete electrical and vacuum failure, how do you propose to power said GPS? What about the flight controls?

Comment: Have you ever piloted an aircraft? (Just to say it: being a pilot is not a prerequisite for participating on Aviation SE, *but* you'll generally be expected to have some idea of aviation matters.) Adding to @RonBeyer's comment above, among the first things you learn when you start flying is to make coordinated turns. In a coordinated turn, the gravity vector points perpendicular to the wings, even though the wings aren't level with the horizon. At that point, a simple sensor won't tell you anything useful; you'll need some kind of inertial reference, typically some kind of gyroscope.

Comment: @user3528438 ...or three things.

Comment: This video shows why a phone's "gravity" sensor or compass in water won't work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9pvG_ZSnCc

Comment: well aware of the fundamental forces of flight. Idevice as simple as a cell phone though has enough accelerometer Hardware that it could probably act as a fairly accurate inertial reference device with the right app, and that would be immune to slip skid or other such aberrations.I know commercials have inertial navigation units but I've never heard of those being used to determine attitude... But I don't see why they couldn't.

Comment: as for the ground track, with small planes, maybe, but a commercial jet traveling at 600 miles an hour will still be traveling fairly close to that when measured at Ground speed, even with a 50 knot headwinds. if they are supposed to be going 600 miles an hour but are indicating 50 knots ground speed, I think that would raise some red flags about a stall.

Answer (score 2):

In the cockpit of every plane I am aware of, there is a compass somewhere. It is the simplest form of a magnetic compass, similar to the "compass in water" you described. Due to physics, a compass will lead or lag when an aircraft turns, therefore it is very difficult to achieve a precise heading. But you can use it to point the aircraft in the general direction (within 10~20 degrees I'd say), and that is very helpful when nothing in your cockpit works.

Also, note that the vacuum pump does not require electricity to operate. For this reason, the Horizontal Situation Indicator (HSI) and the Turn Coordinator are usually powered by different sources. Both need a spinning gyroscope to function. One is powered electrically and the other by vacuum. This is intentional: in the event of either a total electric failure or vacuum pump failure, the remaining instrument can provide turn information. Only when you have a failure of both systems (exceptionally rare), will you loose all turn information.

By the same reason, the primary Attitude Indicator is vacuum powered and the backup Attitude Indicator is electrically powered.

The widespread of tablet devices has led to [applications which serve as backup instruments](http://www.x-plane.com/x-world/hardware/seeker-avionics/) as well. The application is not certified by aviation authorities to replace the on board instruments (at the time); however, more than one pilot has claimed that it saved his life by providing crucial situation awareness during an electric failure.

In an advanced aircraft, such as airliners, the systems are not only redundant, but also designed such that a single problem would not affect both systems. For example, the control cables on the captain side and copilot side are routed differently, making a complete failure extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Voting to close because this question has become a rolling disaster on wheels. NO, a cell phone does NOT have enough sensors to double as an AHRS nor an IRU/INS. Nor does your toy wet compass.

The whole concept of “failure-proof” is pretty loopy... anything much more complicated than a paperweight will have some failure mode. Wet compass: freeze, crack & lose fluid, interference by some large metallic object sitting where it doesn’t belong, etc. Cell phones as failure-proof? Laughable as soon as you say that out loud.

No, I really don’t think that the industry that has turned flying through the stratosphere in a metal tube into the safest activity know to recorded history, has overlooked your phone & toy compass as ways to make things safer.